# Run python dlib library on azure app service

Tags: python, azure, azure-web-app-service

I have created an azure app service for Python 3.4 and installed pip there using this https://bootstrap.pypa.io/get-pip.py script. Everything works fine except when I try to execute `pip install dlib` library the exception occurs:
`RuntimeError: CMake must be installed to build the following extensions: dlib`

Is there a way to install `Cmake` at the machine running this app service?

Comment: You may be able to make that work with serious time investment or you can switch to App Service Linux and build a Dockerfile for your app with all the _pips_ installed - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/containers/tutorial-custom-docker-image

Comment: @Jay, the indispensable. Thank you again for your care, you have helped me so much the other time.
I have tried to deploy a linux web app (https://demostandzerobit.scm.azurewebsites.net/) with one of the public docker files with dlib and python3 from docker hub (https://hub.docker.com/r/adriaalcala/python3-dlib/tags/),  but the app returns `internal server error` when I try to open the address.
I have no experience with docker whatsoever and assume that I need to modify it somehow, so it runs a web server at the correct port somehow. do you know a good tutorial for that?

Answer (score 2):

Here is the solution that worked for me:

Step 0. Create the Flask application in the app.py file for example like this:

```
from flask import Flask
import dlib
app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/')
def hello_world():
    return 'This server is running dlib version: {}'.format(dlib.__version__)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(debug=True,host='0.0.0.0')
```

Step 1. Build a Docker file in the same folder with Python, cmake and dlib (I opted for Python 3). Here is the Dockerfile for this:

```
FROM ubuntu:latest
MAINTAINER Ilya Pukhov "ilya.pukhov@gmail.com"
RUN apt-get update -y
RUN apt-get install -y python3-pip \
    python3-dev \
    build-essential \
    cmake
COPY . /app
WORKDIR /app
RUN pip3 install flask
RUN pip3 install dlib
ENTRYPOINT ["python3"]
CMD ["app.py"]
```

Here is the readymade file at the Docker Hub https://hub.docker.com/r/garinthengineer/dlib-test-2/

Step 2. Create the Web app on Linux in azure, ensure that the  WEBSITES_PORT variable is set to the port number on which your Flask server is listening (by default is 5000) and connect the docker file to it. You may use the Docker Hub link from the previous point. Here is a tutorial for that step https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/containers/tutorial-custom-docker-image#change-web-app-and-redeploy

Profit.

[image]

Comment: Ended up doing this. Despite being fully aware of container benefits, I'm not a fan of it as in my particular case all other apps run on standard app service and benefit from extensions gallery such as let's encrypt.

Comment: @Turowicz But how do you install dlib at the app service? Through a *.whl file?

Comment: I'm running it on a VM since app service machines don't have GPUs.